# Happiness from sunlight is from IR or UV?

Tags: human-biology, brain, sensation, light, radiation

I found this [study](https://www.cell.com/cell/fulltext/S0092-8674(14)00611-4) that shows that UV light makes our skin release feel-good endorphins. [This](https://hms.harvard.edu/news/addicted-sun) is the pop-sci writeup.

On the other hand, it seems like IR is what causes the sense of warmth in the skin when you feel sunlight.

So are there two effects that make us happy when we see the sun? One being physical - IR heat - and the other chemical/biological - endorphins from UV? Is one more important than the other in that feel-good sensation?